# Why do you have to open doors in Cod Zombies?

Tags: call-of-duty-series

Why do you have to open doors in Zombies? Can't you just stay in the room you spawn in?

Comment: I haven't played CoD in ages but if I'm not mistaken you just lose access to more weapons (that will help on later stages) and less points overall

Answer (score 6):

The waves of zombies become progressively harder to deal with, and the weapons you have access to in the initial areas just aren't up to the task.  Opening new areas unlocks new weapons and other bonuses, which are basically essential to surviving later rounds.